# Create two depending models at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to model a system where each user may have many emails (at least one).

Following good normalization rules I created two migrations (some fields removed for brevity):

```
create_table :users do |t|
end

create_table :user_emails do |t|
  t.integer :user_id, null: false
  t.string :email, null: false
end

add_index :user_emails, :email, :unique => true
add_foreign_key :user_emails, :users, dependent: :delete
```

and the following rails models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails, class_name: 'UserEmail', dependent: :destroy

  def self.find_by_email(email)
    UserEmail.find_by(email: email).try(:user)
  end

  validate do
    if emails.count < 1
      errors.add(:emails, "is empty")
    end
  end
end

class UserEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

Now I am not able to create any of those. User cannot be created since it requires at least an UserEmail. At the same time, UserEmail cannot be created beforehand since it requires an user_id.

I believe I have tried any combination of `@user.emails.build` and `@user.emails << e` that I can think of.

How can I solve this really simple problem without renouncing to data consistency (one is saved and the other is not)?

P.s.: I tought that maybe relaxing the validations and using transactions may solve the problem consistently. However I've never used transactions in rails, so any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried @user_email.build_user

Comment: Still reporting validation error in user_id being blank :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

validates_presence_of :user_id only check for any valid integer which might not be a valid user.

But if you use `validates_presence_of :user` and `validates_presence_of :emails`, they will check the user and emails association are valid and not blank.

Also, when you are trying to create the user and the associated email, you are able to do the following code on application level.

```
 user = User.new(name: 'user name')
 user.emails.build(email_address: 'email address')  #build(email: '') for your case.
```

Then, you can save to database with

```
 user.save!
```

Below is the code I tested with.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails, class_name: 'UserEmail', dependent: :destroy
  validates_presence_of :emails, :message => 'User should have at least one email address.'
end

class UserEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_presence_of :email_address
end


[40] pry(main)> u = User.create!(name: 'doh')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Emails User should have at least one email address.

[1] pry(main)> u = User.new(name: 'nice')
=> #<User id: nil, name: "nice", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[2] pry(main)> u.emails.build(email_address: 'hello@world.blah')
=> #<UserEmail id: nil, user_id: nil, email_address: "hello@world.blah", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[3] pry(main)> u.save!
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-07-26 10:14:52.184245"], ["name", "nice"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-26 10:14:52.184245"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "user_emails" ("created_at", "email_address", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-07-26 10:14:52.189757"], ["email_address", "hello@world.blah"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-26 10:14:52.189757"], ["user_id", 5]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
=> true
[4] pry(main)> u.emails.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "user_emails"  WHERE "user_emails"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 5]]
=> 1
[5] pry(main)> u.id
=> 5
[6] pry(main)> u.name
=> "nice"
[7] pry(main)> u.emails
=> [#<UserEmail id: 4, user_id: 5, email_address: "hello@world.blah", created_at: "2014-07-26 10:14:52", updated_at: "2014-07-26 10:14:52">]
[8] pry(main)> u
=> #<User id: 5, name: "nice", created_at: "2014-07-26 10:14:52", updated_at: "2014-07-26 10:14:52">


[19] pry(main)> UserEmail.create!(email_address: 'test@test.org')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User can't be blank
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I adding a NOT NULL constraint on the storage layer is sufficient. I can remove the :user_id presence validation and have the same consistency behavior, with the exception that it now works.

However this looks quite hacky from the rails POW. Any better solution is still really appreciated...